# Hole drilling in a 6" by 12" solid wood beam

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a buddy that has exposed ceilings in his wonderful house they just bought.  In this section of the house there are 6" wide by 12" wide solid wood beams that go from one side of room to the other, a span of about 20'. They are requesting to add 2 modest chandeliers and one ceiling fan to one beam.

What is the maximum hole I can drill vertically through this beam to extend circuitry through to an electrical fan support box?

Comment: Have you considered entering conduit with the wire and routing it around the beam to a surface mounted box?

Comment: Beam size (and thus size of allowed holes) are based on loads and span. How wide is the room (perpendicular to beam), whet is the snow load in your area and how heavy are the chandeliers?

Comment: The question, as it stands, is probably not one we can answer. It would require evaluation of the entire situation by an engineer.

Comment: @DeanMichaud "his wonderful house " if you drill in those beams you will detract from the architectural beauty of the house. Try to find another way to do what your buddy desires. You will probably find a very viable solution - that looks nice and does not do irreparable harm.

Answer (score 3):

Once you drill a hole in an exposed beam you can't undo that ugly mistake. I would use conduit, "wiremold 4000", or a similar product  that can be painted a color that matches the beam making it less conspicuous. Drilling holes in an exposed wood beam is usually a big mistake that lessens the valve of the room.

Comment: I am glad yo said it - because the Beams are part of the architectural beauty and drilling a hole large enough for wire is really a bad idea! not too mention the load rating will be reduced by it.